# How to use one value as Y-max and other as fill in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to show memory usage in GB on numa nodes of host.

Here is my example tibble:

```
library(tidyr)

numa.nodes <- tibble (
  numa_name = c("numa_01","numa_01","numa_01","numa_01","numa_01","numa_01","numa_02","numa_02","numa_02","numa_02"),
  counter_name =c("cpu01","cpu02","cpu03","cpu04","memory_used","memory_total","cpu01","cpu02","memory_used","memory_total"),
    value = c(sample(0:100,4), sample(0:32,1), 32, sample(0:100,1), sample(0:100,1), sample(0:128,1), 128)
)

numa.nodes <- numa.nodes %>% add_row(
  numa_name = c("numa_03","numa_03","numa_03","numa_03","numa_03","numa_03","numa_04","numa_04","numa_04","numa_04"),
  counter_name =c("cpu01","cpu02","cpu03","cpu04","memory_used","memory_total","cpu01","cpu02","memory_used","memory_total"),
  value = c(sample(0:100,4), sample(0:32,1), 32, sample(0:100,1), sample(0:100,1), sample(0:128,1), 128)
  )


numa.nodes <- numa.nodes %>% mutate(counter_name=factor(counter_name,levels = unique(counter_name),ordered = T))
```

Here is how I try in ggplot2:

```
numa.nodes %>% filter(counter_name == c("memory_used", "memory_total")) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = counter_name, y = value, label = value) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  facet_wrap(vars(numa_name), strip.position = 'bottom', scales = "free_x")+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'top',
        axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        strip.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold')) +
        labs(x='Memory',y="Usage %")
```

Here is my result plot:

[image: my result plot]

here is what I need:

[image: what I need]

How to make it in ggplot2 or any other lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. If I understand correctly you want to plot the difference between total memory and used memory. In that case you have to reshape the data to wide compute the difference and then sketch the plot. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
numa.nodes %>% filter(counter_name == c("memory_used", "memory_total")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = counter_name,values_from=value) %>%
  mutate(Diff=memory_total-memory_used) %>% select(-memory_used) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=numa_name,y=memory_total)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(fill='memory_total'),color='black')+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(y=Diff,fill='Diff'),color='black') +
  facet_wrap(vars(numa_name), strip.position = 'bottom', scales = "free")+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_text(aes(y=memory_total,
                label=memory_total),size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(y=Diff,label=Diff),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            size=3)+
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'top',
        axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        strip.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(x='Memory',y="Usage %")+
  labs(fill='Variable')
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:**

```
#Code 2
numa.nodes %>% filter(counter_name == c("memory_used", "memory_total")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = counter_name,values_from=value) %>%
  mutate(Diff=memory_total-memory_used) %>% select(-memory_total) %>%
  pivot_longer(-numa_name) %>%
  mutate(name=factor(name,levels=c('memory_used','Diff'),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=numa_name,y=value,fill=name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black')+
  facet_wrap(vars(numa_name), strip.position = 'bottom',scales = 'free_x')+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_text(aes(label=value),size = 3,position = position_stack(0.5),
            color='white',fontface='bold') +
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'top',
        axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        strip.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(x='Memory',y="Usage %")+
  labs(fill='Variable')
```

Output:

[image]

**Update 2:**

```
#Code 4
numa.nodes %>% filter(counter_name == c("memory_used", "memory_total")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = counter_name,values_from=value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=numa_name,y=memory_total)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(fill='memory_total'),color='black')+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(y=memory_used,fill='memory_used'),color='black') +
  facet_wrap(vars(numa_name), strip.position = 'bottom', scales = "free_x")+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_text(aes(y=memory_total,
                label=memory_total),size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(y=memory_used,label=memory_used),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            size=3)+
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'top',
        axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        strip.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(x='Memory',y="Usage %")+
  labs(fill='Variable')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is closer to what I need but 32GB bar height looks like 128GB bar height here. I wish heights were proportional.

Comment: Also there is no need to calculate diff. "Memory used" is part of "Memory total". You are showing now Diff = Total memory - Used memory = "Free memory space" on "Memory total" bar now. I need to show - "Used memory" on total bar.

Comment: @Maxim I have added an update, please check if that works for you or give me more details!

Comment: There is no need to calculate Diff. You are now loosing Total_memory counter and replacing it with Free_memory counter. In previous code you replaced Used_memory counter with Free_memory counter. But I need Used_memory and Total_memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Layout of facets and label placing etc. is not yet ideal. But maybe this helps...

```
#total memory only
mem.total <- numa.nodes[numa.nodes$counter_name == "memory_total",]

#memory used vs. unused
mem.usage <- numa.nodes[numa.nodes$counter_name == "memory_used",]
mem.usage <- rbind(mem.usage,
                   data.frame(numa_name = mem.total$numa_name,
                              counter_name = "memory_unused",
                              value = mem.total$value - mem.usage$value))
mem.usage$counter_name = factor(mem.usage$counter_name, 
                                levels = c("memory_unused", "memory_used"))

#plot
ggplot(data = mem.usage, aes(x = numa_name, y = value, label = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ numa_name, scales = "free_x") +
  geom_bar(aes(group = counter_name, fill = counter_name),
           stat = 'identity', position = "stack", color = "black") +
  geom_label(data = mem.total, size = 5) +
  geom_label(data = mem.usage[mem.usage$counter_name == "memory_used",], 
             size = 5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "black")) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]